# Unable to change image size in my draw function

Tags: swift

In my meme application, I want the user to be able to put text on image. To make this possible I am using UIGraphics. In my scene, I have an image drawn on the background and a text showing on the foreground.

Here is my code for generating the so said image :

```
func GenerateMemeFrom(image: UIImage, topText: NSString, bottomText: NSString) -> UIImage {
        let scale: CGFloat = 4
        let size = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * scale, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height * scale)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)

        let textAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [
            NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack", size: 200)!,
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white,
        ]
        
        let ratio = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width / image.size.width
        let imageSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * scale, height: image.size.height * ratio * scale)
        image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: imageSize))
        
        let point = CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * scale / 2, y: 100)
        let rect = CGRect(origin: point, size: image.size)
        topText.draw(in: rect, withAttributes: textAttributes)
        
        let generatedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        
        return generatedImage!
    }
```

Here is what I have on my screen : [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2ySs.jpg)

But whether I put scale equal to 2 or 4, it changes nothing in the application. I want to be able to change size based on screen width. Furthermore, I want the image to be centered. Is there any way to do so ?

Comment: (Please, do not think I'm an expert!) To me, "scale" deals with pixels and... density? Think of how you want/need @1, @2, @3 for various devices. I actually think you are close to what you want. If you really think it gets down to image size - and it may not be the issue - how about resziing things a different way? I have two pieces of code that may help. (1) Code that extends UIImage and changes it's size to a 640x640 frame and you can change it to whatever size you need. (2) A way to generate a UIImage from any UIView, including it's subviews. Will either of those help?

Comment: Yes please share it ! Thanks !

Comment: set image height and width equals to view frame width & height.